# I have all these items in a textview, how to put them in listview now

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview

I am parsing JSON into a textview and i need some help trying to put that into a listview instead. I know this might be very easy for some, but my main focus of confusion is that in a textview, you are setting the text using the setText function. I am also new to android, so I don't have this basic down yet, but I appreciate any help in advance, thank you.

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        try {
            String buildings = getJSON("http://iam.colum.edu/portfolio/api/course?json=True");

            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(buildings);
            JSONArray queryArray = new JSONArray(buildings);
            //queryArray = queryArray.getJSONArray(0);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
                list.add( queryArray.getString(i) );

            }

            String finaltext="";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
                // chain each string, separated with a new line
                sb.append(queryArray.getString(i) + "\n");
            }
            // display the content on textview
            tv1.setText(sb.toString());
             //tv1.setText(arr[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("JSONError", e.toString());
        }
    }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you add your `ListView` in your layout file, and then in the code you set an `Adapter` on the `ListView`, which holds the data. And then all the magic is going to be done for you.

Please read
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews

So in your case it would look something like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

...

JSONArray queryArray = new JSONArray(buildings);
//queryArray = queryArray.getJSONArray(0);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<queryArray.length(); i++) {
    list.add( queryArray.getString(i) );
}

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will take the content of your `list` and create one `ListView` item for each entry. The text is set to the layout file `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` which is provided by android.

If you change the content of the `ArrayAdapter` (and thus the `ListView`) you have to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to inform the system that the content has changed.

To change the layout, or add an `Adapter` for other data sources, please refer to the documentation.